# Explanation of 4-wire Delta Transformer Phasor Diagram

Tags: transformer, phasor, delta

I have been studying some of the Tx configurations for metering. I've been looking at a booklet called the Power Measurements Handbook, which is sort of an informal resource in the metering world. I came across their phasor diagram for the 4-wire delta and it is not making sense. I cannot find any videos online that show the same diagram. Could someone explain how these angles are derived? See image attached[image]

The explanation in this video, for instance, makes more sense:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFAihxGZqvQ

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between the phase diagrams you are used to seeing and this one is that the Neutral is in a different place.  All of the voltages are referenced to Neutral.  In any analysis, any voltage in the analysis can be your phase reference point.  This author has chosen the voltage AB to have zero phase shift, and all other phase shifts are referenced to AB.  So looking at the three delta ends, we have the standard phase relationship where the three phases are 120 degrees apart:

[image]

Since voltage AN is wound on the same core as voltage AB, the voltage is in phase with AB but as a center tap it is 1/2 the amplitude:

[image]

So AN also has a phase shift of zero - that is, it is in phase with AB.

Now BN is also wound on the same core as AB, but it is in the opposite direction.  So it also has 1/2 the amplitude of AB but is out of phase (or phase shifted by 180 degrees):

[image]

It is easy to see AN and BN, and their phase relationships.  CN is a little less intuitive.  The chart below shows CA (from our first diagram) on the same chart with AN (which we have calculated earlier).
[image]

But CN must equal CA + AN.  See what happens when we calculate CN by adding each point on AN to each point on CA:

[image]

This provides 208VRMS with a 270-degree phase shift from AB.

Of course, the current in the phases themselves retain the 120-degree phase shift from phase to phase.